# Does Scapy bypass Dummynet?

Tags: python, delay, scapy, icmp, ipfw

Does [Scapy](http://www.secdev.org/projects/scapy/) bypass [Dummynet](http://info.iet.unipi.it/~luigi/dummynet/) (IPFW in general)?

It really looks like it does. I'm adding a large extra delay to each outgoing and incoming packet, and everything slows down apart from packets sent with Scapy.

```
$ ipfw add pipe 1 from any to any
$ ipfw pipe 1 config delay 500ms
$ ping www.google.com
PING www.l.google.com (173.194.34.18) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from par03s02-in-f18.1e100.net (173.194.34.18): icmp_req=1 ttl=54 time=1011 ms
64 bytes from par03s02-in-f18.1e100.net (173.194.34.18): icmp_req=2 ttl=54 time=1010 ms
```

So it seems OK. But as soon as I send packets with Scapy, here's what happens:

```
>>> from scapy.all import *
>>> p = IP(dst="www.google.com", ttl=1) / TCP(sport=222, dport=2999)
>>> ans,unans = sr(p*3)
>>> ans[0][1].time - ans[0][0].sent_time
0.0002701282501220703  #usual value for such RTT
```

Is there any way to force it to pass through dummynet?

**EDIT** If only I had another machine at my disposal, I could use dummynet there and direct all my traffic to it, before it gets into the Internet. I would prefer to do everything locally, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The author of Scapy replied to me in Scapy's mailing list:

> Try the same solution as for this question:
>   http://trac.secdev.org/scapy/wiki/FAQ#Icantping127.0.0.1.Scapydoesnotworkwith127.0.0.1orontheloopbackinterface
>   (using raw sockets)

It worked!  Here's the paragraph from the above link :

> **I can't ping 127.0.0.1. Scapy does not work with 127.0.0.1 or on theloopback interface**
>
> The loopback interface is a very special interface. Packets going
>   through it are not really assembled and dissassembled. The kernel
>   routes the packet to its destination while it is still stored an
>   internal structure. What you see with tcpdump -i lo is only a fake to
>   make you think everything is normal. The kernel is not aware of what
>   Scapy is doing behind his back, so what you see on the loopback
>   interface is also a fake. Except this one did not come from a local
>   structure. Thus the kernel will never receive it.
>
> In order to speak to local applications, you need to build your
>   packets one layer upper, using a PF_INET/SOCK_RAW socket instead of a
>   PF_PACKET/SOCK_RAW (or its equivalent on other systems than Linux) :

```
>>> conf.L3socket
<class __main__.L3PacketSocket at 0xb7bdf5fc>
>>> conf.L3socket=L3RawSocket
>>> sr1(IP(dst="127.0.0.1")/ICMP())
<IP  version=4L ihl=5L tos=0x0 len=28 id=40953 flags= frag=0L ttl=64 proto=ICMP chksum=0xdce5 src=127.0.0.1 dst=127.0.0.1 options='' |<ICMP  type=echo-reply code=0 chksum=0xffff id=0x0 seq=0x0 |>>
```